# how to implement a readUInt16BE function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, byte

The readUint16BE function in node.js, the function declare is:

```
buf.readUInt16BE(offset, [noAssert])
```

doc: 
http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint16be_offset_noassert

> Reads an unsigned 16 bit integer from the buffer at the specified offset with specified endian format.

how to implement in golang? thanks very much

or golang have some function like  readUint16BE ??

Answer (score 4):

You can use the encoding/binary package.
Ex: (http://play.golang.org/p/5s_-hclYJ0)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)

    // Put uint16 320 (big endian) into buf at offster 127
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(buf[127:], 320)

    // Put uint16 420 (little endian) into buf at offster 127
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(buf[255:], 420)

    // Retrieve the uint16 big endian from buf
    result := binary.BigEndian.Uint16(buf[127:])
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", result)

    // Retrieve the uint16 little endian from buf
    result = binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(buf[255:])
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", result)

    // See the state of buf (display only 2 bytes from the given often as it is uint16)
    fmt.Printf("%v, %v\n", buf[127:129], buf[255:257])
}
```